# Spring integration splitter aggregator memory leak

Tags: spring-integration, splitter

I have created the following project:

https://github.com/adispennette/splitter-aggregator-leak-example

to test a memory leak I am seeing in another application.
I am using eclipse to run the junit and monitoring the memory using jconsole.
once the test starts I connect to the JUnit runner and do a manual GC.
from that point I let it run and the memory just continues to increase.
The theory here is that the aggregator is not releasing properly.

I have attempted to get this to release the collections in every way I can think of but it keeps growing.

is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to discard late-arriving messages, the aggregator has to retain metadata for released groups. Set `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` to remove this metadata when the group is released. However, late arriving messages will now form a new group.

If you want the default behavior but are concerned about the small amount of memory required for the metadata, you can configure a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` as described [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#reaper). Empty groups can be expired on a different schedule to partial groups.

Comment: I already have a reaper set up, and I added the property you mentioned and the memory graph still continues to rise until the heap is exhausted.

Comment: What makes you think it's the aggregator that's leaking? Take a heap dump and look at what's on it.

Comment: Class Name Shallow Heap Retained Heap

java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[16] @ 0x78281e6b8 80 1,313,772,416
segments java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap @ 0x78281e688 48 1,313,772,464
groupIdToMessageGroup org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore @ 0x78281cce8
48 1,675,589,944
messageGroupStore org.springframework.integration.store.MessageGroupStoreReaper @ 0x78281ccc0 40 88
targetObject org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable @ 0x782856c78 56 152

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? A problem similar to this was fixed 2.5 years ago in 2.2.0 and 2.1.5. https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2833 The current release is 4.1.3

Comment: It appears you are using at least 4.0 (from [this](https://github.com/adispennette/splitter-aggregator-leak-example/blob/master/research-dev/src/main/java/com/test/transformer/SplitterTestTransformer.java#L6). Can you build a simpler test case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: SI v2.1.0 is being used, this is most likely the issue from the jira.  Thanks so much for the assistance.

Comment: I'm glad to see that you have found the common language! @GaryRussell +1 from me :-). @peekay, be sure to specify a version in the future and try to upgrade your app to most recent version. Although it isn't clear to me how it can be SI 2.1, since you use the stuff from SF 4.x like `@Header` or even `Message` class...